# Map active instances and remove after when are disposed

Tags: c#, controls, hashcode

I have a dynamic number of Contols and i need to generate a UNIQUE identifier for some Control instances ( Label, Button, CheckBox, .... ) at runtime.
To do that, I have a function which browse my principal UserControl and for each "valid" Control instance will generate an identifier with the function `RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(<myinstance>);`. So I obtain an **ID** and I save it into an Hashtable composed by:

Key:**ID** - Value:**string**.

The problem is that when the instance will be destroyed, i need to remove the key added in the Hashtable, otherwise the Hashtable will grow only beacuse it preserves Ids of objects already disposed.
I'm not sure that what I did is the best approach for this kind of problem, but I think is a good solution for my specific context; so what I want to know is if exist a method more efficent or if exist a way to know when a Control instance is going to be disposed (without override the Dispose method for each Control).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an event in the Control class called `Disposed` that gets fired when the control's Dispose function is called. You can handle this event for each control you create to get notified when the control is disposed and then remove the appropriate ID from your Hashtable.

Comment: I asked explicitly: (without override the Dispose method for each Control)

Comment: I didn't suggest overriding the Dispose method. I suggested handling the Disposed event.

Comment: Correct, but what i meant was something of higher level. Doesn't exist anything? Anyway the Disposed event could be an interesting solution! Many thanks !

Comment: Generally speaking, whenever you want to know if information about an object has changed, there are two ways of finding out: ask it explicitly or have it tell you automatically. In your case, asking explicitly would involve periodically polling all the controls in the Hashtable to see if they still exist, which is perfectly viable but is also a lot more work than just handling the event and waiting for the controls to tell you when they get disposed.